# Why does `.keys()` return `Index` for a Pandas `DataFrame`?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, series

My ultimate objective is to get a specific value by group label after taking the mean of some groups. To do this I would like to grab a list of the column names so I can select the column with the group label I'm interested in. However, the behavior of the resulting `DataFrame` is not as expected:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'x': ['a','b','c','a','b','c'], 'y': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]})
means = df.groupby('x').mean()
```

`type(means)` gives `pandas.core.frame.DataFrame`

`means.keys()` gives `Index(['y'], dtype='object')`

However, the documentation for the `keys` method says:

> Get the 'info axis' (see Indexing for more)
>
> This is index for Series, columns for DataFrame and major_axis for Panel.

The result of `mean.keys()` appears to contradict this, as `mean` is a `DataFrame` but it is returning an `Index` as if it were a `Series`. Is this the intended behavior? If it really were a series I could look up the desired value very easily, but it still acts like a DataFrame in most ways.

This is pandas 0.24.2 on Python 3.7.3

Comment: `This is index for Series, columns for DataFrame` , so keys return the columns , anything wrong ?`means.columns
Out[874]: Index(['y'], dtype='object')`

Comment: `Index` objects are used for both the DataFrame index and the DataFrame columns (slightly confusing I suppose).

Comment: `index` are indexes for `axis=0`, and `columns` are indexes for `axis=1`

Answer (score 1):

The result of your groupby statement is indeed a dataframe. It is a one column dataframe, but still a dataframe.

As such, when you use the keys method, you should get the columns label, in this case 'y'

```
means.keys()
Index(['y'], dtype='object')
```

Whenever you select a single column in a dataframe, pandas returns a series. So selecting columnn 'y' and using keys should return the index.

```
means['y'].keys()
Index(['a', 'b', 'c'], dtype='object', name='x')
```

The term index in this case is confusing as both columns and rows in Pandas are index items.